# How to get all deployment process request within a Timeframe using UrabanCode Deploy REST API?

Tags: deployment, ucd, urbancode

I am looking for REST API option in UrabanCode Deploy to get all deployment process within a particular time-frame. Let's say

```
- All deployment process request id submitted within 24 hours. 
- All Deploy process request submitted in Last 7 Days etc.
```

I have checked the possibility in `applicationProcessRequest` Rest API with `filterValue` option as suggested in [this question](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/191154/how-to-get-historical-deployment-information-in-ud/) but no luck. Its displaying all process request.

```
http://localhost:8443/rest/deploy/applicationProcessRequest/table?filterValue_submittedTime=1473282726868
```

I am looking filter option to limit the result based on date field.
Does anyone know `UrbanCode REST API` that return all `applicationProcessRequest` id's within a time-frame?

I will really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get list of deployment process request id from `/rest/report/adhoc` endpoint.
Parameters are:

- **dateRange**: custom, currentWeek, currentMonth
- **date_low**: UnixTimestamp in milliseconds (Required if dateRange is
  custom)
- **date_hi**: UnixTimestamp in milliseconds (Required if
  dateRange is custom)
- **orderField**:  Order field
- **sortType**: Sort type asc/desc
- **type**: Report type 
            com.urbancode.ds.subsys.report.domain.deployment_report.DeploymentReport

**Syntax:**

```
http://localhost:8443/rest/report/adHoc?dateRange=custom&date_low=<START_DATE>&date_hi=<END_DATE>&orderField=application&sortType=asc&type=com.urbancode.ds.subsys.report.domain.deployment_report.DeploymentReport
```

e.g

```
http://localhost:8443/rest/report/adHoc?dateRange=custom&date_low=1472702400000&date_hi=1474430400000&orderField=application&sortType=asc&type=com.urbancode.ds.subsys.report.domain.deployment_report.DeploymentReport
```